# using jest + typescript in monorepo

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm currently trying to use jest in a Typescript monorepo (not Lerna or anything just `baseURL` and `paths`, also, not my decision) and one of the files I'm testing imports a something from the monorepo.

```js
import {publish, subscribe} from "message-bus"
```

Now in my `tsconfig.json` I have:

```
...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./packages",
        "paths": {
            "message-bus":["message-bus/src"],
        }, 
...
```

and in the package `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
...
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^message-bus/(.*)$': "../message-bus/src/$1"
  }
...
}
```

Even with all this in place `jest` complains that it cannot find the module `message-bus`. Can you please help me fix my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that your `jest.config.js` is at the root of your package and not the monorepo, you need the `moduleNameMapper` to form a path that can be understood from any location. You do this by starting with the directory that the `jest.config.js` file is in and then building your path from there. This will create an absolute path to your mapped module.

Also, you need the slash (`/`) in your regex capture group because it's not always in the path.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  ...
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^message-bus(.*)$': path.join(__dirname, '../message-bus/src$1')
  }
  ...
}
```